# Getting runtime error information from IXMLDOMDocument::transformNode function

Tags: c++, error-handling, xslt, ixmldomdocument

I'm using [`IXMLDOMDocument::transformNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms761399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to apply an XSLT transform using C++ code that looks a little bit like this:

```
CComPtr<IXMLDOMDocument2> spXMLDoc;
// load spXMLDoc

CComPtr<IXMLDOMDocument2> spXSLDoc;
// load spXSLDoc

BSTR *pResult;
HRESULT hr = spXMLDoc->transformNode( spXSLDoc, pResult );
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    // Handle me
}
```

This code **works**, however if the transform fails then I don't know how to get any information about where or why it failed - at the moment its failing (on a complex XSLT with multiple includes) with a HRESULT of `E_FAIL` - is there any way I can get some more detail on why its failing?

I've already tried the `parseError` property to get more error detail:

```
IXMLDOMParseError *parseError = NULL;
hr = spXMLDoc->get_parseError(&parseError);
if ( !FAILED( hr ) )
{
    long errorCode = 0;
    hr = parseError->get_errorCode(&errorCode);
    // etc...
```

The call to `get_parseError` succeeds, however the call to `get_errorCode` fails with HRESULT `S_FALSE`, indicating that there was not a parse error.  [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tells me that there are two types of error - parse errors and runtime errors.  It shows how to handle both, however appears to be JavaScript oriented - in my case no C++ runtime errors are thrown.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I'm not sure from C++.  You might try a quick command line transformation to help find the error in XSLT.  There's a number of errors where the XSL will load, but can't transform. For an example pop an  somewhere in the XSL file to trigger this type of error.

Here's a sample command line transformation tool.  Write to transform.js and run cscript.exe transform.js from a command line

```
var strDOMObject = "MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument";
var strHTTPObject = "MSXML2.XMLHTTP";
var strTemplateObject = "MSXML2.XSLTemplate";

function transform( xml, xsl ) {
    var xslt = new ActiveXObject( strTemplateObject );
    var xmlReturn = new ActiveXObject( strDOMObject );
    var xslProc;
    try {
        xslt.stylesheet = xsl;
    } catch( e ) {
        throw e;
    }

    xslProc = xslt.createProcessor();
    xslProc.input = xml;
    xslProc.transform();
    return xslProc.output;
}


try {
    var xml = new ActiveXObject( strDOMObject );
    xml.load( "id.xml" );
    var xsl = new ActiveXObject( strDOMObject );
    xsl.load( "id.xsl" );
    WScript.Echo( transform( xml, xsl ) );

} catch( err ) {
    WScript.Echo (err.description );
}
```

Hope this helps, and that you can find out the C++ answer.